# Word Problem Involving Completing Tasks in Different Amounts of Time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Two men $A$ and $B$ can together complete a task in $12$ days. If $B$ alone completes the same task, he takes $10$ days more than $A.$ How many days does it take for $B$ alone to complete the entire task?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A performs a tasks/day.
B performs b tasks/day.
A performs 1 task in 1/a days.
B performs 1 task in 1/b days.
1/b = 1/a + 10 days.
A and B perform a + b tasks/day.
A and B perform 1 task in 1/(a + b) days.
1/(a + b) = 12 days.

Justify those steps,
solve those two equations for a and b,
and thusly deduce the answer.